# If IE tag not working for IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I got a script for a quantity box where you can add or remove items.

However it's not working in IE probably because there is a button inside an anchor tag, what I wanted to do is use an onClick function that will be used when a user uses IE.

This would do it, I thought but I found out this is not working as of IE11.

Anyone know a workaround? I want to use an onClick function only when IE is used, since the quantity box works fine in other browsers.

```
<!--[if lt IE 11]>
<![endif]-->
```

If it helps anyone, this is the code I am talking about that does not work in IE.

```
<a href="?del='.$key.'" class="minus" >
    <input type="button" class="minus" value="-" id="min">
</a>

<input type="text" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="'.$value.'" name="quantity" min="1" step="1">

<a href="?add='.$key.'" type="button" class="plus">
    <input  type="button" class="plus" value="+">
</a>
```

Comment: Wrapping `<input>` elements in `<a>` tags? What?

Comment: Take a look to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx. I guess user agent parsing is an option here.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: UA parsing is very unreliable, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus absolutely true but to workaround a bug on a specific browser (version) it may be an option. Feature detection to isolate a browser + its version is much more unsafe.

Comment: don't hack around using invalid html, fix the html

Comment: I know @cebrus, but it works in other browsers, I want to use onClick for IE, but I don't know how to make sure it's only used when a user is on IE.

Comment: @Cerbrus oh no, I didn't see the **reason** he needs to detect IE. :| :| :| user50248: just fix your HTML, no need to workaround anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Conditional comments are no longer supported as of IE 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).**

You *could* use a meta tag to make IE render the page in IE9 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

Then, the conditional statements should work again.

Please have a look at the article I linked to for some more details.

---

However, the big problem here is that you are wrapping your inputs in `<a>` tags. That's invalid syntax, and most likely the reason the page is misbehaving.

Comment: Yeah I am looking at other ways to do it, thanks for taking the time to answer! I will look into emulating IE9 mode.

Answer (score 5):

**Internet Explorer 10 and 11 do NOT support conditional `if` comments. They are only supported uptil IE9.**

You can read more about them on [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

The dropping of support is listed in [this article from the MSDN site itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

From the same page:

> If the page works correctly in other browsers, consider using feature detection to treat Internet Explorer 10 like other browsers. Otherwise, add the following meta tag near the top of the page to opt into Internet Explorer 9 behavior:
>   HTML
>
> `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`

**This workaround should be avoided. Keep your code semantic and these won't be required in most cases.**

In your case, don't wrap `input` elements in anchor/any other tags. Use a `label` instead.

Comment: I know, I said that in my topic, I need a workaround for IE11.